# Highcharts - Diagonal line X/Y axis

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, drawing

Is there any way of showing a 1:1 diagonal line in Highcharts? I am looking for a line which X and Y values always match.

I know how to render a line in Highcharts using the renderer, however, I don't want an independent line but one that reacts to the chart resizing/zooming. A series with [(0,0),(1,1)] is not really an option (it would affect zooming).

Something like this except x and y axis might vary their value due to zooming.

[image: Chart with a diagonal line equally crossing X and Y axis]

Comment: You can still do it with the renderer, or with a series, but you'll have to create the logic to re-draw it on zoom - there is nothing built into highcharts to do this (AFAIK)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by detecting the `setExtremes()` event on you axes, and fire a function to get the axis extremes and draw a line.
(or, in this case, I used the `afterSetExtremes()` function)

In my example I did it by using a line series. I assume you can adapt it to use the renderer since you've already used the renderer to draw the line initially.

```
function redrawLine(chart) {
    var xExt = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
    var yExt = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();

    chart.series[1].setData([
        {'x':xExt.min,'y':yExt.min},
        {'x':xExt.max,'y':yExt.max}
    ]);
}
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/feLdzpux/

Of course, if your intent is to compare observed values to predicted values, then re-drawing the line when you zoom in is counter productive and misleading - the line should not move based on the zoom level - it should always be constant.